# Why is this not behaving responsively?

Tags: html, css, yui-pure-css

I have the below SASS and HTML code. I'm using PureCSS by Yahoo.

**What I'm trying to do**

I'm trying to get this to have a 3 column layout for large desktop size screen, with the `pure-lg-3-24` classes essentially acting as margins, then collapse it to a 1 column layout for mobile screens.

**What actually happens**

When I add `pure-u-1` to my classes below (in a large desktop size browser width), all the html content falls into one column.  If I remove `pure-u-1` it all collapses together and the text sits on top of each other, rendering it unreadable.  Why is this?  What's the starting point for getting it to behave responsively?  I thought nested grids were allowed in [PureCSS](http://purecss.io/grids/).

**SASS**

```
#layout {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e1e1e1;

  .pure-g {

    h1 {
      font-family: Georgia, serif;
      a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #990000;
      }
    }

    h2 {
      font-size: 1em;
      font-weight: normal;
    }
    mark {
      color: #990000;
      background: none;
      font-weight: 700;
    }

  }

}

ul.languages {
  list-style-type: none; 

  li.active {
    font-weight: 700;

    a {
      color: #666;
    }
  }

  li {
    display: inline;
  }

}
```

**HTML**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/pure/0.6.0/pure-min.css">
 :
<header id="layout" class="pure-g">
  <div class="pure-u-1 pure-u-lg-3-24">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="pure-u-1 pure-u-lg-18-24">

    <div class="pure-g">
      <div class="pure-u-1 pure-u-lg-12-24">
        <h1><a href="/">Trial Dates</a></h1>
      </div>
      <div class="pure-u-1 pure-u-lg-12-24">
        <p>Contact us at <mark>(800) 800-COLLECT</mark></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="pure-g">
      <div class="pure-u-1 pure-u-lg-12-24">
        <h2>Tagline</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="pure-u-1 pure-u-lg-12-24">
        <ul class="languages">
          <li class="active">
            <a href="#">English</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Español</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">漢語</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="pure-u-1 pure-u-lg-3-24">&nbsp;</div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 2):

As it turns out, according to a part of the [documentation](http://purecss.io/start/#responsive-grids), you need to add the following in addition to the core pure css:

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/pure/0.6.0/grids-responsive-old-ie-min.css">
<![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/pure/0.6.0/grids-responsive-min.css">
<!--<![endif]-->
```